# Should questions that address the same issue in different ways be marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

At the moment, we have the question "[Why do women have more lower body strength than upper body strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-women-have-more-lower-body-strength-than-upper-body-strength)". Seems like a fairly clear cut question.

Several years back, I answered the question "[Compared to their overall strength, do women have greater lower body strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29642/compared-to-their-overall-strength-do-women-have-greater-lower-body-strength-in/29687)"

Although in my answer I did identify a small difference in the ratios of upper / lower body strength between the sexes, it wasn't nearly as great as I thought it would be. The ratios were essentially the same, but not exactly.

So, is the first question a duplicate, to which the answer is essentially "they don't, and here's proof", or should it be left as is because the very limited sample size I used did reveal a small difference?

(Note: I'm not a statistician, I don't know if it would be seen as a statistically significant difference or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen in general practice on other sites (Both beta and graduated), the litmus test is that if the answer on the possible dupe target completely answers the new question being asked (Even if it is completely different), then it is considered a duplicate.

This is usually a little bit of a thorny issue, and on busier sites gets regularly debated as to "what is a dupe?", but that is the general theme that holds true.